# Segmentation Fault when accessing strtok Pointer

Tags: c, string, strtok

I'm trying to split a string with strtok into it's words.
Now a strange behavior occurred:

When compiling with Xcode and LLVM the program works as it should.

But compiling with gcc causes an error when accessing the pointer created by strtok

Here is the code:

```
char *toTest ="Dieser String hat Groß und Kleinschreibung!";
char* shouldResults[]={"dieser","string","hat","groß","und","kleinschreibung"};
char* tokens = getTokenWords(toTest);
int i = 0;
int error = 0;
while (tokens != NULL){
    char * toTest = shouldResults[i];
    if(strcmp(tokens,toTest) != 0){
        error = 1;
        break;
    }
    tokens = strtok (NULL, " ,.-");
    i++;
}
return error;
```

The getWordTokens function is declared in another module and looks like this:
auth.c:

```
char* getTokenWords(char *text){
    char *str = strdup(text);
    int i;
    for(i = 0; str[i]; i++){
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
    }
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok (str," ,.-");
    return pch;
}
```

The header looks like this:
auth.h

```
#ifndef _AUTH_H
#define _AUTH_H
//creates tokens out of words from string
char* getTokenWords(char *text);

#endif
```

I import the auth.h by adding:

```
#include "auth.h"
```

in the main module.

Can you help me with this error?

Comment: Your code looks like it should run.  There are a couple of bugs - `getTokenWords` leaks `str` and the last comparison fails because of the ! at the end of Kleinschreibung! - but this just results in `error` getting (correctly) set.  If you still get a segfault, can you post a full runnable example please?

Comment: gcc and clang both do fine with this code on MacOS 10.8. gcc 4.2.1. clang 4.0. valgrind clean.

Comment: I use 
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)

Comment: This code could run off the end of shouldResults, it doesn't with this test data, but with other test data it could. ( If strtok() returns more elements than the number in shouldResults ).

Comment: What line does gdb tell you it barfs on? And/or post a complete compilable example

Comment: Has this something to do with the "memory" of strtok's last result  when he uses NULL as first argument? Maybe the function is inlined or something?

Comment: Ok I found out that the error is caused by importing the function from another module. I will update my post

Comment: From what I see, that shouldn't change anything. The design is bad, having the first call to strok() in one function and the rest in the other is asking for bugs.

Comment: Maybe you should do what Charlie Burns told you. That update doesn't help, I guess.

Comment: Do you link in libc in both your modules? You should only link the modules together with glibc at the end. Can you show how you compile this?

Answer (score 1):

The function strtok modifies the string you pass to it. You pass the pointer `toTest` to it which points to a string literal - not an array of characters. My guess is that XCode and LLVM store the string literal `toTest` points to in writeable memory, whereas gcc puts it in read only memory. I may be wrong but I would try declaring `toTest` as an array.

```
char toTest[] ="Dieser String hat Groß und Kleinschreibung!";
```